# Property 'equal' does not exist on type 'typeof Validators'

Tags: angular, typescript, angular12

I have the following code in a `.ts` file in an Angular 12 app:

```
import { Validators, ValidatorFn, AbstractControl, ValidationErrors } from '@angular/forms';

declare module '@angular/forms' {
  export namespace Validators {
    export let equal: (this: typeof Validators, firstControlName: string, secondControlName: string) => ValidatorFn;
  }
}

Validators.equal = function(firstControlName: string, secondControlName: string): ValidatorFn {
  return equalValidator(firstControlName, secondControlName);
};

export const equalValidator = (firstControlName: string, secondControlName: string): ValidatorFn => {
  return (control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null => {
    const firstControl = control.get(firstControlName);
    const secondControl = control.get(secondControlName);

    if (firstControl && secondControl && firstControl.value !== secondControl.value) {
      secondControl.setErrors({ equal: true });
      return null;
    }

    secondControl?.setErrors({ equal: null });
    secondControl?.updateValueAndValidity({ onlySelf: true });

    return null;
  }
}
```

This shows no errors in the editor so then I use it in a component in another `.ts` file where I even get autocompletion for the `equal` function:

```
Validators.equal('password', 'passwordConfirmation');
```

However, when I compile the application I get an error at the line above:

> Property 'equal' does not exist on type 'typeof Validators'.

What am I missing?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like the file that contains the validator is dropped out of the compilation, because there are no modules that reference it.

A good place to include it would be `main.ts`:

```
...
import { AppModule } from "./app/app.module";
import "./app/shared/validators.ts";

platformBrowserDynamic().bootstrapModule(AppModule)
...
```

[Demo](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-55tqa7?file=src/main.ts)

Answer (score -1):

For checking if password === confirmPassword:

1. Global Password Equal Validator:

```
import { FormGroup } from '@angular/forms';

export function PasswordConfirm(password: any, confirmPassword: any) {
    return (formGroup: FormGroup) => {
        const CONTROL = formGroup.controls[password];
        const MATCHING_CONTROL = formGroup.controls[confirmPassword];

        if (MATCHING_CONTROL.errors && !MATCHING_CONTROL.errors.passwordMismatch) {
            return;
        }

        if (CONTROL.value !== MATCHING_CONTROL.value) {
            MATCHING_CONTROL.setErrors({ passwordMismatch: true });
        } else {
            MATCHING_CONTROL.setErrors(null);
        }
    };
}
```

2. Add validator to form in Typescript:

```
form = this.fb.group(
        {
            firstName: [undefined, Validators.required],
            lastName: [undefined, Validators.required],
            email: [undefined, Validators.required],
            bornAt: [undefined, Validators.required],
            password: [undefined, [Validators.required, Validators.pattern('^(?=.*[a-z])(?=.*[A-Z])(?=.*[0-9])(?=.*[!@#$%^&*_=+-]).{8,}$')]],
            confirmPassword: [undefined, Validators.required],
        },
        {
            validator: [PasswordConfirm('password', 'confirmPassword')],
        }
    );
```

Comment: That does not answer my question as what I need is a custom generic `equal` validator that I can apply in many situations and components. If I move my code to the same TS file as the component everything works fine.

Comment: apologies @MiguelMoura, i have edited my answer for you, now using a global password validator :)

Comment: Yes, I also know that placing the validator on a different file with export will work. The question is how to use as a Validators function and in different files?